# ICriteria Restriction on Expression

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

How should be written the following query with the NHibernate's ICriteria API:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Order>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Property1 + Property2", confirmation.Ammount));
```

What I need is to compare an expression (Property1 + Property2) to given value (confirmation.Ammount).

I'm using NHibernate 2.0 (I can't switch to newer version at the moment).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1

```
.Add(Expression.Sql("(Property1 + Property2) = ?", confirmation.Ammount, NHibernateUtil.Int32));
```

option 2

writing your own Projection [see here](http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html)

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq(new ArithmeticOperatorProjection(
    "+", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property("Property1"), Projections.Property("Property2")
    )
)
```